# Solution for React app implementation of client and server side rendering in an existing app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

I have a React app that serves all static files (including React js) from a CDN and uses a Nodejs server as an API.

Now I want to implement server side rendering.

lets say as an example the app is a sale board for cars, where users can publish their car for sale. each car ad will have a "car page" with its details images etc..

So for each car ad to be indexed by search engines, a server side implantation is needed.

Here are the options tested/came to mind:

1. Use one of the html generators libraries like [react-static](https://github.com/nozzle/react-static) or [react-snap](https://github.com/stereobooster/react-snap) or [react-snapshot](https://github.com/geelen/react-snapshot). Those don't do the trick because pages needs to by updated dynamically, so if user updates his ad the pages needs to be updated and not on the next build. (building on each update and pushing to a CDN seems not right).
2. forget about the CDN and move all requests to the server like in this example - [How to server-side render React, hydrate it on the client and combine client and server routes](https://github.com/MarvelousWololo/ssr-react). At this point the app is pretty large and changing such a significant deployment aspect will be a shame + don't want to lose CDN advantages.
3. Creating a new service server that will be used only for delivering those pages (viewing pages is not behind login). Then deploying `Nginx` for rerouting traffic with `pages` path to the server and all other request to the api server. Have not figured out how to combine it with a CDN yet...

Surly Im missing on other solutions but this was what came to mind after some research

Any suggestions and thoughts would be welcomed

Comment: Doesn't matter if you use a pre-rendering solution or do server-side rendering. Your problem is how to notify the CDN that your content changed and it needs to invalidate the old version. Depends on what CDN you use, but most allow you to notify them of content changes. I'd go with (1) and a custom solution for cache busting on the CDN side.

Comment: I use CloudFront.. Yes it is possible. I Though there will be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of the only solution. Only input I can give you is that CloudFront has a habit of _changing_ the HTML it caches by "minifying" it (which will break fast hydration), but you can disable that.

Comment: also I would have to disable or reduce to a couple of minutes the cashing or user updates wont be seen. Another problem is that I would want to connect those pages to the state on the client for future features, and not sure its possible with #1 solution.. is it?